# Background-position in css

Tags: css, css-sprites

Can we use more than 2 images for single navigation. That means when we hover on that image it will shows 6 different images. Is it possible to make for a single navigation image? If possible means how?

I think you are all understand this

[alt text http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/2786/mubeen.gif](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/2786/mubeen.gif)

Comment: This question is extremely hard to understand. Please clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @phleet:I add image in my question please go through

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. Are those dots moving? When are they changing positions?

Comment: @phleet: when i hover on image the dot will move left to right. Is it possible in css-sprites

Comment: this is not possible except using jQuery to shift the `background-position` programmatically, or an animated GIF that shows the moving dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (at the moment - cross browser) only set one bg image on an element. If you want to change it on hover or whatever, just add an `a`-tag with `href` set on `#`:

```
<a class="img" id="thatoneimg" href="#"></a>
```

And then in the css:

```
a.img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
a#thatoneimg {
  backround-image: url(staticimg.jpg);
}
a#thatoneimg:hover {
  backround-image: url(movingimg.gif);
}
```

That should work cross browser. You need the `a`-tag for it to work in IE.

Edit:
As Starx said, just make the second image a .gif with an animation. It will not use sprites but it will work.

Comment: ya you are correct but i need more than two images while hovering

Comment: Eventually you will be able to use CSS transitions.

http://vision-media.ca/resources/css/css-transformations-animations-and-transitions-examples

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you want to continously change the position of your background image while you hover over one button.

If that's right, then I suggest making a static image as background image and changing the image to a GIF animated image on hover

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, it's possible, but you will have to have 6 different HTML elements to contain the background image at 6 different positions.

Comment: i need 6 different images on a same place when i navigate on a image

Comment: @Mubeen I don't get it. Can you make a graphical example?

Comment: I add image in my question please go through